# Search Bar Is Not In Coded Position HTML

Tags: html, css

again.

I am stuck with my search bar where it is not the position and the size i had coded in it.

Supposedly the search bar shall be look like in the following link:  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_searchbar.asp

But eventually, after i typed the coded, the search bar had different size and is not the position i wanted to be. here is the image below:  [image: search bar not in position]

Your help is much appreciated as i am still learning in this programming languages.

```css
<!-- ---------------------------------------START OF CSS -------------------------------- --><style>
/*----------------------START OF CSS PAGE BACKGROUND-----------------*/

body {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}


/*----------------------END OF CSS PAGE BACKGROUND-----------------*/


/*----------------------START OF CSS STICKY NAVBAR AND DROPDOWN BUTTONS-----------------*/

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  background-color: #38444d;
  min-height: 45px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /*Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

li {
  float: center;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Style the search box inside the navigation bar */

.topnav .search-container {
  float: right;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav .search-container {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav a,
  .topnav input[type=text],
  .topnav .search-container button {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
  }
}


/*----------------------END OF CSS STICKY NAVBAR AND DROPDOWN BUTTONS-----------------*/


/*----------------------------------------START OF CSS FOOTER----------------------------*/


/*footer basic*/

footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #111;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}


/*footer title*/

.footer-content h3 {
  font-size: 2.1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  line-height: 3rem;
}

.footer-content p {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #cacdd2;
}


/*footer social media icons */

.socials {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1rem 0 3rem 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.socials li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.socials a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1.1px solid white;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.socials a i {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  width: 20px;
  transition: color .4s ease;
}

.socials a:hover i {
  color: aqua;
}


/*footer menu */

.footer-menu {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.footer-menu ul {
  display: flex;
  background: transparent;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-menu ul li {
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.footer-menu ul li a {
  color: #cfd2d6;
  border: 1.3px solid white;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #27bcda;
}


/*footer credit section*/

.footer-bottom {
  background: #000;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-bottom p {
  float: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.footer-bottom p a {
  color: #44bae8;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-bottom span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: .4;
  font-weight: 200;
}


/*footer to be responsive */

@media (max-width:500px) {
  .footer-menu ul {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}


/*
     footer {
       text-align: center;
       padding: 3px;
       background-color: DarkSalmon;
       color: white;
     }
     */


/*---------------------------------------END OF CSS FOOTER--------------------------------*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(1)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <div class="search-container">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
      <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</ul>

<h3>Sticky Navigation Bar Example</h3>
<p>The navbar will <strong>stick</strong> to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer do not support sticky positioning and Safari requires a -webkit- prefix.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="footer">
  <footer>
    <div class="footer-content">
      <h3>Foolish Developer</h3>
      <p>Raj Template is a blog website where you will find great tutorials on web design and development. Here each tutorial is beautifully described step by step with the required source code.</p>
      <ul class="socials">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="footer-menu">
        <ul class="f-menu">
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-bottom">
      <p>copyright &copy; <a href="#">Foolish Developer</a> </p>
    </div>

  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: hi mplungjan. i am sorry, as i did not able to understand what do you mean?

Comment: I just formatted your html into a snippet

Comment: okay. thank you very much. may i know ho do you do that as i not familiar with most of the stack overflow features.

Comment: `.search-container { text-align: right; flex: 1 1 auto; }` this is the css rule you are missing to make the search container shrink to the end of its container and aligning its content to the right. Plus your css selectors often use `.topnav` but there isn't any on your html

Comment: What position did you want it to be in? For me it works fine

Comment: you may see this following link; https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_searchbar.asp

i want the search bar in the same size with the navbar and on the right side of it.

Comment: @Diego De Vita, may i know how shall change the .topnav to the one which i supposed to replace it with?

Comment: a `DIV` is not a valid child of `UL` - the `div.search-container` should be within a `li` tag

Comment: @ Professor Abronsius, so how shall i adjust the code to work so? i try moving the search html code here and there between the navbar position but still not working.

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP?

Comment: Also why tagged with JavaScript...

Comment: this code, is done in PHP programming language. i tagged JavaScript accidently has there is JavaScript previously which is removed as it  does works with the code just now.

Comment: @mplungjan, is there any solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I found with your code was indexing. So I made some changes in the indexing of the elements of Nav bar

And Other chanage I made in the css of Nav bar to aling the search bar at right

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="footer.php" />

    <style>
      
    /*----------------------START OF CSS PAGE BACKGROUND-----------------*/
    
    body {
      background-color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      margin: 0;
    }
    /*----------------------END OF CSS PAGE BACKGROUND-----------------*/
    /*----------------------START OF CSS STICKY NAVBAR AND DROPDOWN BUTTONS-----------------*/
    
    .nav {
      display: flex;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      /* overflow: hidden; */
      background-color: #38444d;
      min-height: 45px;
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      /*Safari */
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;

      /* Chanage I made */
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 0 2%;
      /* Chanage I made */

    }

    .nav ul {
      display: flex;
      list-style-type: none;



    }
    
    li {
      float: center;

    }
    
    li a,
    .dropbtn {
      display: inline-block;
      color: white;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li a:hover,
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    li.dropdown {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #dcdcdc;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    /* Style the search box inside the navigation bar */
    
    .topnav .search-container {
      float: right;
    }
    
    .topnav input[type=text] {
      padding: 8px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      font-size: 17px;
      border: none;
    }

  
  
    
    .topnav .search-container button {
      float: right;
      padding: 6px 10px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      margin-right: 16px;
      background: #ddd;
      font-size: 17px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .topnav .search-container button:hover {
      background: #ccc;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .topnav .search-container {
        float: none;
      }
      .topnav a,
      .topnav input[type=text],
      .topnav .search-container button {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 14px;
      }
      .topnav input[type=text] {
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
      }
    }
    /*----------------------END OF CSS STICKY NAVBAR AND DROPDOWN BUTTONS-----------------*/
    /*----------------------------------------START OF CSS FOOTER----------------------------*/
    /*footer basic*/
    
    footer {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: #111;
      height: auto;
      margin: 0px;
      padding-top: 0px;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .footer-content {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      text-align: center;
    }
    /*footer title*/
    
    .footer-content h3 {
      font-size: 2.1rem;
      font-weight: 500;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      line-height: 3rem;
    }
    
    .footer-content p {
      max-width: 500px;
      margin: 10px auto;
      line-height: 28px;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #cacdd2;
    }
    /*footer social media icons */
    
    .socials {
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 1rem 0 3rem 0;
      background: transparent;
    }
    
    .socials li {
      margin: 0 10px;
    }
    
    .socials a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      border: 1.1px solid white;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    
    .socials a i {
      font-size: 1.1rem;
      width: 20px;
      transition: color .4s ease;
    }
    
    .socials a:hover i {
      color: aqua;
    }
    /*footer menu */
    
    .footer-menu {
      margin: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    .footer-menu ul {
      display: flex;
      background: transparent;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .footer-menu ul li {
      padding-right: 10px;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .footer-menu ul li a {
      color: #cfd2d6;
      border: 1.3px solid white;
      padding: 6px 15px;
      border-radius: 50px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .footer-menu ul li a:hover {
      color: #27bcda;
    }
    /*footer credit section*/
    
    .footer-bottom {
      background: #000;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 3px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .footer-bottom p {
      float: center;
      font-size: 14px;
      word-spacing: 2px;
      text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    
    .footer-bottom p a {
      color: #44bae8;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .footer-bottom span {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      opacity: .4;
      font-weight: 200;
    }
    /*footer to be responsive */
    
    @media (max-width:500px) {
      .footer-menu ul {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
    }
    /*
     footer {
       text-align: center;
       padding: 3px;
       background-color: DarkSalmon;
       color: white;
     }
     */
    /*---------------------------------------END OF CSS FOOTER--------------------------------*/
  
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
      <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="javascript:void(1)" class="dropbtn"
            >Dropdown <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i
          ></a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="search-container">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
          <input
            class="search_bar"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search.."
            name="search"
          />
          <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h3>Sticky Navigation Bar Example</h3>
    <p>
      The navbar will <strong>stick</strong> to the top when you reach its
      scroll position.
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer do not support sticky positioning
      and Safari requires a -webkit- prefix.
    </p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.</p>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="footer">
      <footer>
        <div class="footer-content">
          <h3>Foolish Developer</h3>
          <p>
            Raj Template is a blog website where you will find great tutorials
            on web design and development. Here each tutorial is beautifully
            described step by step with the required source code.
          </p>
          <ul class="socials">
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="footer-menu">
            <ul class="f-menu">
              <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-bottom">
          <p>copyright &copy; <a href="#">Foolish Developer</a></p>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much with your help. i am a small inquiry here. are we suppose to use ".nav" or "ul @ li'  in css? because i am quite confuse as different sites shows different ways to use on it.

Comment: First, there is no `@` in css, but I assume this is a typo. You use each, depending on the spefitiy needed for the project. If you are a beginner in CSS, get familiar with how specifity works in CSS then you understand when to use which.

Comment: your code work well. but when type your code in mine and execute it. the search bar seems to appear on the right side but below the navbar. i hope you understand what i mean here. it is not in the same line with the "home", "news" and "dropdown" navbar but below it on the right side.

Comment: so how shall i placed the magnifying glass with the search bar inside the navbar?

Comment: @thanabalantharmalingam That navbar appers below line for small width so u need to add responsiveness to do that

Comment: for putting icon in search bar you will have to give icon 'Position:absolute' and then 'right:0 '

Comment: Learn flex rather than using float

Comment: @saurav, thank you very much for the information you have provided as it helps me a lot.

Comment: Are you on discord . I may help you a lot as it will also help me

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you are using a div inside of ul tag. You should not do that.
I have added a new div to wrap the ul menu and the form component. Check it.

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="footer.php">

      <!-- ---------------------------------------START OF CSS -------------------------------- -->
      <style>
        /*----------------------START OF CSS PAGE BACKGROUND-----------------*/
        
        body {
          background-color: white;
          font-size: 20px;
          margin: 0;
        }
        /*----------------------END OF CSS PAGE BACKGROUND-----------------*/
        /*----------------------START OF CSS STICKY NAVBAR AND DROPDOWN BUTTONS-----------------*/
        
        .topnav{
          display:flex;
          justify-content: space-between;
          align-items: center;
          /* overflow: hidden; */
          background-color: #38444d;
          min-height: 45px;
          position: -webkit-sticky;
          /*Safari */
          position: sticky;
          top: 0;
        }
        ul {
          display: flex;
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
        
        li {
          float: center;
        }
        
        li a,
        .dropbtn {
          display: inline-block;
          color: white;
          text-align: left;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        li a:hover,
        .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
          background-color: red;
        }
        
        li.dropdown {
          display: inline-block;
        }
        
        .dropdown-content {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          background-color: #f9f9f9;
          min-width: 160px;
          box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          z-index: 1;
        }
        
        .dropdown-content a {
          color: black;
          padding: 12px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: block;
          text-align: left;
        }
        
        .dropdown-content a:hover {
          background-color: #dcdcdc;
        }
        
        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
          display: block;
        }
        /* Style the search box inside the navigation bar */
        
        .topnav .search-container {
          float: right;
        }
        
        .topnav input[type=text] {
          padding: 8px;
          margin-top: 10px;
          font-size: 17px;
          border: none;
        }
        
        .topnav .search-container button {
          float: right;
          padding: 6px 10px;
          margin-top: 8px;
          margin-right: 16px;
          background: #ddd;
          font-size: 17px;
          border: none;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        .topnav .search-container button:hover {
          background: #ccc;
        }
        
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
          .topnav .search-container {
            float: none;
          }
          .topnav a,
          .topnav input[type=text],
          .topnav .search-container button {
            float: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 14px;
          }
          .topnav input[type=text] {
            border: 2px solid #ccc;
          }
        }
        /*----------------------END OF CSS STICKY NAVBAR AND DROPDOWN BUTTONS-----------------*/
        /*----------------------------------------START OF CSS FOOTER----------------------------*/
        /*footer basic*/
        
        footer {
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          background: #111;
          height: auto;
          margin: 0px;
          padding-top: 0px;
          color: #fff;
        }
        
        .footer-content {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          flex-direction: column;
          text-align: center;
        }
        /*footer title*/
        
        .footer-content h3 {
          font-size: 2.1rem;
          font-weight: 500;
          text-transform: capitalize;
          line-height: 3rem;
        }
        
        .footer-content p {
          max-width: 500px;
          margin: 10px auto;
          line-height: 28px;
          font-size: 14px;
          color: #cacdd2;
        }
        /*footer social media icons */
        
        .socials {
          list-style: none;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          margin: 1rem 0 3rem 0;
          background: transparent;
        }
        
        .socials li {
          margin: 0 10px;
        }
        
        .socials a {
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #fff;
          border: 1.1px solid white;
          padding: 5px;
          border-radius: 50%;
        }
        
        .socials a i {
          font-size: 1.1rem;
          width: 20px;
          transition: color .4s ease;
        }
        
        .socials a:hover i {
          color: aqua;
        }
        /*footer menu */
        
        .footer-menu {
          margin: 0px;
          padding-bottom: 5px;
        }
        
        .footer-menu ul {
          display: flex;
          background: transparent;
          align-items: center;
        }
        
        .footer-menu ul li {
          padding-right: 10px;
          display: block;
        }
        
        .footer-menu ul li a {
          color: #cfd2d6;
          border: 1.3px solid white;
          padding: 6px 15px;
          border-radius: 50px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        .footer-menu ul li a:hover {
          color: #27bcda;
        }
        /*footer credit section*/
        
        .footer-bottom {
          background: #000;
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 5px;
          padding-bottom: 3px;
          text-align: center;
        }
        
        .footer-bottom p {
          float: center;
          font-size: 14px;
          word-spacing: 2px;
          text-transform: capitalize;
        }
        
        .footer-bottom p a {
          color: #44bae8;
          font-size: 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        .footer-bottom span {
          text-transform: uppercase;
          opacity: .4;
          font-weight: 200;
        }
        /*footer to be responsive */
        
        @media (max-width:500px) {
          .footer-menu ul {
            display: flex;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
          }
        }
        /*
         footer {
           text-align: center;
           padding: 3px;
           background-color: DarkSalmon;
           color: white;
         }
         */
        /*---------------------------------------END OF CSS FOOTER--------------------------------*/
      </style>
      <!-- ---------------------------------------END OF CSS -------------------------------- -->

      <!-- -------------------------------------START OF HTML ------------------------------- -->
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="header">
        <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
        <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="topnav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="javascript:void(1)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
        <div class="search-container">
          <form action="/action_page.php">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
          </form>
        </div>
        </div>

      <h3>Sticky Navigation Bar Example</h3>
      <p>The navbar will <strong>stick</strong> to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
      <p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer do not support sticky positioning and Safari requires a -webkit- prefix.</p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>

      <div class="clear"></div>

      <div class="footer">
        <footer>
          <div class="footer-content">
            <h3>Foolish Developer</h3>
            <p>Raj Template is a blog website where you will find great tutorials on web design and development. Here each tutorial is beautifully described step by step with the required source code.</p>
            <ul class="socials">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="footer-menu">
              <ul class="f-menu">
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-bottom">
            <p>copyright &copy; <a href="#">Foolish Developer</a> </p>
          </div>

        </footer>
      </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. your code work well. but when type your code in  mine and execute it. the search bar seems to appear on the right side but below the navbar. i hope you understand what i mean here. it is not in the same line with the "home", "news" and "dropdown" navbar but below it on the right side.

Comment: the above code does not align the magnifying glass with the search bar

Comment: i do not mean on the aligning between the magnifying glass with the search bar. however, both the magnifying glass with the search bar is shown below the navbar on the right side of it. so how shall i placed it in side the navbar?